# Trying to return char array via pointer and it's giving incorrect results

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char *getUserInput() {
    char command[65];

    //Ask the user for valid input
    printf("Please enter a command:\n");
    fgets(command, 65, stdin);

    //Remove newline
    command[strcspn(command, "\n")] = 0;
    return command;
}

int main() {
    char *recCommand = getUserInput();
    printf("%s", recCommand);
    return 0;
}
```

When this code is executed, this is the console:

```
Please enter a command:
Test <-- this is the command I entered
*weird unknown characters returned to console*
```

Why are there weird unknown characters being returned to console instead of "Test"?

Comment: Local variables are disabled when exiting the scope of the function.

Comment: So instead of returning a pointer to "command", I should be returning the char array command itself?

Comment: try `return strdup(command);` this make copy string.( secure the area in heap) then `free(command);` at main.

Comment: Why do we need to free(command)? Are you referring to here the command located inside the getUserInput scope or inside the main scope?

Comment: area of heap isn't release, it will still be secured.

So the user must be freed.

Comment: lifetime of area reserved to heap is not related to the scope. It exists until you explicitly release.

Comment: @AdamNygate for a fix [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297169/how-to-make-an-array-return-type-from-c-function)

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are returning the value of a local variable.  Try putting this:

```
char *getUserInput() {
    static char command[65];

    //Ask the user for valid input
    printf("Please enter a command:\n");
    fgets(command, 65, stdin);

    //Remove newline
    command[strcspn(command, "\n")] = 0;
    return command;
}
```

Comment: I come from a C# background, is it possible to instead just return the value of command from the getUserInput function?

Comment: @AdamNygate: Yes, it's possible. But it require a bit of work to allocate memory and then make sure it gets released in a timely manner. In C, this is probably your best bet.

Comment: The trouble with this is that if you call `getUserInput()` twice, the second value overwrites the first.  This can cause problems in multi-threaded programs where multiple threads call the function, and it can also cause problems in single-threaded programs where you call the function twice before using the returned value from the first call.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some more research, it seems that the best way is to actually pass in a char array from the main function in which to store the input from getUserInput.

Here is my revised code:

```
void getUserInput(char *command) {
    //Ask the user for valid input
    printf("Please enter a command:\n");
    fgets(command, 65, stdin);

    //Remove newline/return carriage
    command[strcspn(command, "\n")] = 0;
}

int main {
    char recCommand[65];
    getUserInput(recCommand);
    printf("%s", recCommand);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hardcoding the length of your array into your function is a bad idea. At least make it `void getUserInput(char * command, size_t size)` or similar.

Comment: I've made the length a macro and defined it in a commonmacros.h file, the requested input will always be 65 chars long (64 + \0)