# Return an array of files

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create a function that returns an array of files but I couldn't find a way to access that array outside of the function.
Here's what I tried:

```
FILE* *arquivoescrita(int k) //gerar nome de arquivo
{
  char filename[sizeof("file1000000000000.txt")];
  static FILE* arquivos[2];
  for (int i = k; i < k+2; ++i)
  {
   sprintf(filename, "file%d.txt", i);
   arquivos[i] = fopen(filename,"r");
  }
  return arquivos;

}
```

And I'm calling the function inside main like this:

```
FILE* psaidas[2];
psaidas = arquivoescrita(0);
```

And the error I get is

```
error: array type 'FILE *[2]' is not assignable
psaidas = arquivoescrita(0);
```

How can I access this kind of array?

Comment: You see that you have a double pointer return type and you're returning a single pointer inside the function into a single pointer outside the function through that double pointer return type? While you can store a pointer of any depth in any pointer of any other depth, when you go to dereference the pointer, you still have to have the correct data type and levels of dereference. You also appear to be trying to assign a static array size to a dynamic array.

Comment: Does that mean I returned the array arquivos in the wrong way?

Comment: Usually in c you return pointers and values by reference; because by the time you access it from the returned value it's gone. I do not really understand what you want to do with this code so I could not refactor it for you. But try something like : void archivoescrita(File ** files, int k) thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an array return type from C function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297169/how-to-make-an-array-return-type-from-c-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one issue in returning a `FILE **` array of open file stream, you need to know how many are actually open. You have a couple of choices, (1) pass a pointer to the function and update the pointer to reflect the number of files successfully opened, or (2) what probably makes more sense, is to pass a `FILE *` *array* as a parameter to the function and return the number of files successfully opened to be use as an index back in the calling function. (you could also simply check the stream before attempting to read from it)

For example, if you declared file pointer array `FILE *fparray[MAXF] = {NULL};` in `main`, you could simply pass that as a parameter to be filled in your function. e.g.

```
nfiles = openmulti (fparray, 0, MAXF);
```

Your function would then take the array, just as any other type of array, and fill the elements with open *and validated* `FILE *` elements:

```
int openmulti (FILE **fp, size_t k, size_t n)
{
    char fname[MAXFN] = "";
    size_t i, idx = 0;

    for (i = k; i < n; i++) {
        sprintf (fname, "file%zu.txt", i);
        fp[idx] = fopen (fname, "r");
        if (!fp[idx]) 
            continue;
        idx++;
    }

    return (int)idx;
}
```

(the beginning number `file#.txt` is passed as `k` and then number of files to open is passed as `n`)

A short example opening `file0.txt` and `file1.txt` in the function for reading back in the calling function could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXF = 2, MAXFN = 256 };

int openmulti (FILE **fp, size_t k, size_t n);

int main (void) {

    FILE *fparray[MAXF] = {NULL};
    size_t i, nfiles;

    nfiles = openmulti (fparray, 0, MAXF);  /* populate array */

    if (nfiles < MAXF)       /* validate number of open files */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: '%zu' of %d files open.\n", 
                nfiles, MAXF);

    for (i = 0; i < nfiles; i++) {  /* read/output file contents */
        printf ("\ncontents of 'farray[%zu]'\n\n", i);
        char buf[MAXFN] = "";
        while (fgets (buf, MAXFN, fparray[i]))
            printf ("%s", buf);
        fclose (fparray[i]);        /* close file after reading */
    }

    return 0;
}

int openmulti (FILE **fp, size_t k, size_t n)
{
    char fname[MAXFN] = "";
    size_t i, idx = 0;

    for (i = k; i < n; i++) {
        sprintf (fname, "file%zu.txt", i);
        fp[idx] = fopen (fname, "r");
        if (!fp[idx]) 
            continue;
        idx++;
    }

    return (int)idx;
}
```

**Example Input Files**

```
$ cat file0.txt
1.
2.  hello -- file0.txt
3.

$ cat file1.txt
1.
2.  hello -- file1.txt
3.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/filemultiopen

contents of 'farray[0]'

1.
2.  hello -- file0.txt
3.

contents of 'farray[1]'

1.
2.  hello -- file1.txt
3.
```

Unless there is some critical need to return `FILE **`, it seems to make things a bit more straight forward to pass an array to the function and return the number of files successfully opened. Both ways are possible, whatever fits your needs.

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: I didn't really need to return FILE**, my core problem was creating the FILE* vector. You cleared my doubts. I will try to adapt the code you provided to my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a pointer to the static array. That's fine. But C will not magically copy the array for you into another location. You can change your declaration:

```
FILE**psaidas;
psaidas = arquivoescrita(0);
```

And this will work. But at this point, `psaidas` will be pointing in to your `static FILE *` array. So if you call `arquivoescrita` again, it will be overwritten.

If that works - and it probably will work - then proceed. If you have to worry about calling `arquivoescrita` multiple times before you finish with the files, then you must either use `malloc` or `calloc` to *dynamically allocate* your result within `arquivoescrita` or you may choose to copy the array after you receive it:

```
FILE * psaidas[2];

memcpy(psaidas, arquivoescrita(0), sizeof(psaidas));
```