# How to return string from function in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char pointer();

void main() {
    char*name = "Paz Leviim", **p_name = &name;
    *p_name = pointer();
    printf("Now it's %s", *p_name);
    getchar();
}
char pointer() {
    char name_to_main[100];
    printf("The value now is Paz Leviim\nPlease set value:");
    scanf_s("%[^\n]%*c", &name_to_main,100);
    return name_to_main;
}
```

How can I return the value of variable name_to_main to the pointer *p_name?

Comment: Pass an array (and its size) as *arguments* to the function, and let it fill in that array.

Comment: char != char* , and main() should return int , not void.

Comment: You can't. Either define `name_to_main[]` in `main()` and pass as an argument, or use `malloc()` to allocate storage within `pointer()`. And consider a more meaningful name for the function `pointer()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an array return type from C function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297169/how-to-make-an-array-return-type-from-c-function)

Comment: What does strcpy do? What does strdup do?

Comment: You could return a struct that embeds an array - if it's not allocated on the stack (wel, you can still return it but that's UB).

Comment: I often wonder why sometimes we see things like `"%[^\n]%*c"`, which I can't decipher, alongside fundamental beginner errors like in the rest of the function.

Comment: You should also change `&name_to_main` to `name_to_main`, since arrays decay to pointers to their first elements in most expressions, including function calls.

Comment: @RingØ -- note that you can define a `struct` wrapping the array _within_ the function, and return it. The value will be copied to the receiving variable (which must be a compatible `struct`).

Comment: I've removed the & in the name_to_main and still not working

Comment: @Paz -- that was only one of a very large number of mistakes. [You should get a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn from.

Comment: @DavidBowling Totally right! It's actually quite difficult to return something stack-allocated from a struct, as it's returned by value!

Comment: @KenY-N, it's the result of copy & paste coding.  The OP probably doesn't understand that in any detail either, but they found it on the Internet -- quite possibly even right here on SO.

Comment: In fact, looking at the arguments to that `scanf_s()` call, I'm *confident* that the OP does not fully understand it.

Comment: @Paz The simplest solution is just to change it to `static char name_to_main[100];`.  This is not a perfect solution, and it has several drawbacks, but it should get you started.

Comment: I know that `static` in most cases can be useful but in this case I've got again the error

Comment: Again, @Paz -- threre are _many_ errors in your code, and we are not a debugging service. That said: `char pointer();` --> `char * pointer(void);`, and `void main() {}` --> `int main(void) {}` should help.

Comment: Now my code it's works perfect :)

Comment: Thanks for everyone here I was should to do only `static char name_to_main[100]` and `char*pointer()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char*pointer(char*now);

void main() {
    char*name = "Paz Leviim", **p_name = &name;
    *p_name = pointer(*p_name);
    printf("Now it's %s", *p_name);
    getchar();
}
char*pointer(char*now) {
    static char name_to_main[100];
    printf("The value now is %s\nPlease set value:",now);
    scanf_s("%[^\n]%*c", &name_to_main,100);
    return name_to_main;
}
```

Now all working :)